# Create Bluetooth PAN between iPhone and Windows (Reverse Tethering)

Tags: windows, bluetooth, iphone, pan

It's really easy to create a Bluetooth personal area network between iPhone and MAC OS X.

On Windows, it's quite difficult. We can pair iPhone but the link icon never appears in iOS status bar.

The goal is to let the iPhone reach local network and access Internet.

How to create a Bluetooth PAN under Windows?